# Jasmine TypeError: obj.display is not a function

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm writing spec to test a js function srvDisplay in file sample.js:

```
//sample.js:
srvDisplay: function()
{
  //some code
  let ret = obj.displayReq();

 //some code
}
```

where obj is declared as global in sample.js as:

```
let obj = MY.AppServ.getService(serviceName);
```

My spec is as shown below:

```
//sample.t.js

describe('Display service testing', function()
{
   it('testcaseDisplay', function()
   {
     let context = null;
     context = g_jsTest.loadFile('sample.js');//some custom code to load file

     context.displaySpy = jasmine.createSpy();

     let fakeDisplayObj = {
       displayReq : context.displaySpy 
     };

     context.MY.AppServ.getService = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(fakeDisplayObj);

     context.srvDisplay();  //get type error here: TypeError: obj.displayReq is not a function

  });
});
```

I am spying on "MY.AppServ.getService" which should return fakeDisplayObj which in turn contains obj.displayReq(). Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you check whether in the tested object `MY.AppServ.getService` is the same as `context.MY.AppServ.getService` from the test case?

Comment: Thanks for checking the issue. I managed to resolve this by making "obj" declaration using VAR instead of LET as:
    var obj = MY.AppServ.getService(serviceName);
The issue looks to be that var at global scope means global variable in ES6. let at global scope means block scoped.